# Django and ReactJS Project: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:12) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, webpack

I know there's a lot of similar questions out there but I've tried to do what was suggested and I just can't seem to solve this error. So I'm working on a project using Django and ReactJS. I am using Webpack and Babel to connect front end and back end. I keep getting this error when I run the frontend:

ERROR in ./src/components/App.js 14:12

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:12)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
|     return (
>        <div className="App">
|             <Router>
|                  <Navbar />
|                     <Routes>
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-35
```

I will attach my webpack.congig file and babel.config file. Any help would be appreciated!

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      //   include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      //   exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
      //   use: ['babel-loader']
      // }
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage.js";
import AddGamePage from "./AddGamePage.js";
import PlayersPage from "./PlayersPage.js";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './Navbar';


const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                 <Navbar />
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path='/' element={< HomePage />}></Route>
                        <Route exact path='/games/addGame' element={< AddGamePage />}></Route>
                        <Route exact path='/players' element={< PlayersPage />}></Route>
                        <Route exact path='/login' element={< LoginPage />}></Route>
                    </Routes>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

index.js

```
import App from "./components/App";
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.85.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.10"
  }
}
```